# Select a distinct list of substrings from one of the fields in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have rows such as

- [ISSUE] This is a sample issue
- [WEBSITE] A bug in the website
- Note that this row doesn't contain anything inside square brackets
- [WEBSITE] Another bug in the website
- [TRACKER] It is not live!
- Some rows will have them in the [middle] but I don't want them

etc..

Assume the field is called "Title" and the table is called "Issues". All items in that column start with a string within square brackets. There is no definitive list of what words can come inside the square brackets. no restriction on the length also. I need not get it if the field doesn't start with such a string.

I want to get the word inside the pair of square brackets and get a unique list of those words.

I want to select a distinct list of all the [XYZ]s. For example, in the list above, the query should return the following list of strings:

- ISSUE
- WEBSITE
- TRACKER

It is a combination of substring logic, and distinct query. The logic might go like **Find the index of the first [ and the first ] and get the string between that and from the list, make a unique list**. I am finding it nearly impossible to write it in a single MySQL query. What is the query that will get that list?

Comment: I believe a MYSQL REGEX may suit your needs, have you tried utilizing a REGEX to accomplish your goals?

Comment: No I haven't. I am only fooling around with string functions and dead-ends :D I am not a SQL guy, but forced into a situation where I have to deal with it. Will try to find out how to employ regex in mysql. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I would try:

```
select distinct `Match` from (SELECT MID(Title,instr(Title,'[') + 1,instr(Title,']') - instr(Title,'[') -1) As 'New_Title'
FROM Issues u Where instr(Title,'[') > 0 AND instr(Title,']') > instr((Title),'[')) tbl
```

Sorry this took so long, I had to figure out how to return the string.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a table which contains a field named Title.  The title may start with the string you are looking for and you only want it if it starts with the string. You also want the result to be distinct.

This query will do that.

```
SELECT Issue, Website, Tracker FROM `Issues` Where distinct(Title) LIKE '[SOMETHING]%'
```

Comment: No you have misunderstood. I edited my question. There is only one column called "Title". Its values can start with any string within square brackets. I want a distinct list of all those strings that are there within the square brackets in the beginning of the fields... Issue, Website and Tracker are not columns. They are the result of the query - Strings.

Comment: So you only wan thte strings inside the square brackets[]

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct (case when title REGEXP '^[[]' then
        concat(substring_index(title, ']', 1),']') end ) as title
FROM test.issue i
where title REGEXP '^[[]';